# How to convert rows to columns in unix

Tags: unix

I want my Unix file output, which has each value output on a new line, to be converted into grouped rows as shown below.

Say my output file in Unix looks like this:

```
jobname
userid
starttime
endtime
jobname2
userid
starttime
endtime
```

I want the output to be:

```
jobname1 userid starttime endtime
jobname2 userid starttime endtime
```

Comment: Are you trying to run a bash script? Or Python? Or C++? or ??

Comment: What you describe in the question is that you have a column and you want to convert it to several rows, that is, "convert columns to rows" **not** "convert rows to columns"

Answer (score 10):

This is a minimal `awk` solution:

```
awk 'ORS=NR%4?" ":"\n"' input.txt
```

#### output

```
jobname userid starttime endtime
jobname2 userid starttime endtime
```

(If you want to align the fields, pipe to `column -t`)

Answer (score 6):

This will paste each four consecutive lines as four tab-delimited fields:

```
cat source_file | paste - - - - > destination_file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a shell script, you can do this as the number of lines to be printed in the output seems to have to fixed length:

```
while read line1; do
  read line2
  read line3
  read line4
  echo $line1 $line2 $line3 $line4 >>output
done <file
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < file | sed -r 's/(\w+ +){4}/&\n/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of ugly, but doesn't require a shell script:

```
cat outputfile | tr "\n" " " | sed -e 's/\W*\(\w*\) \(\w*\) \(\w*\) \(\w*\)\W*/\1 \2 \3 \4\n/g'
```