# Bash to turn files of lines into an n column CSV

Tags: bash, csv, data-manipulation

I have data like this:

```
A 


B

C  D


E 
F

G

H I
```

I want it to look like this:

```
A,B,C
D,E,F
G,H,I
```

How can I achieve this using command-line tools?

---

This question has each data-cell on its own line: [How to convert rows to columns in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941991/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-in-unix)

Comment: What is your exact input? What is your exact output? Without those, it is not easy to provide suggestions

Comment: .. and what did you try for yourself?

Comment: @Inian The data is too big (and confidential) to post on here. A solution I know how to do would involve JavaScript / Python, but I think it would be quicker to use existing commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following command could help you.

```
xargs -n 3 <  Input_file |  tr ' ' ','
```

Comment: Sorry, I got my data a bit wrong. Sometimes the columns are on the same line and separated by spaces.

Comment: @sdgfsdh, please check once given links and see if they help you, let us know on same then.

Comment: my data is not as clean as in those links

Comment: @sdgfsdh: For the input given in question, the above answer should work. If the input is not as one in question, modify it to show us the actual question

Comment: @sdgfsdh: did you run the answer on your input in question, it produced a comma separated format as expected